# Correct setup for a simple CDbCriteria in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

This fails when I use $currentUser->id in my CollectionController.php

> $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
>
> $criteria->condition = 'tbl_userId=:tbl_userId';
>
> $criteria->params = array(':tbl_userId' =>**$currentUser->id**);
>
> $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Collection', array('criteria'=>$criteria));

But if I just plug a literal in the params array my query comes back correct.

> $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
>
> $criteria->condition = 'tbl_userId=:tbl_userId';
>
> $criteria->params = array(':tbl_userId' => **12**);
>
> $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Collection', array('criteria'=>$criteria));

What's the quickest Yii-way to verify my var? $currentUser->id

I'm new to PHP / Yii... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

echo out `$currentUSer->id` from the controller. Don't execute the query that is failing and the view should render with what $currentUser->id is. Nothing  Yii style, but it's a quick way to find out what if anything the $currentUser is returning

Comment: i would prefer using **var_dump($currentUser)**

Comment: Yep, I tend to use echo to see if what a property returns. If nothing I tend to use vardump on the obj/array or print_r to do more digging. Glad it's fixed